# Text alignment justify while knitting to a word file from rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown, text-justify

This should be simple, but I am not being able to justify the alignment of my markdown text while knitting to word. I tried some solutions found on the internet while some worked only in the visual editor, while I actually knit to a word document, the justification doesn't show. Is there a code that I can put in the YAML or the body to justify?